# Entering no character for input in C

Tags: c, input, char, scanf, delimiter

Is there a way for the user to enter nothing as input(for character array) in C?
I tried the following:

1. Using a `'\n'` character as delimiter: `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` it gave me junk.
2. Used a custom delimiter like ' ` '. But additional task was required as in case if it was entered in between, etc.
3. Tried using command line arguments for input string (as we know no input gives `One argument expected`)
4. Tried entering `null` by `alt+space`. Did not work either.

Please suggest me a new way or correct me if I am doing any of the above steps wrong. 
Note: I am using Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "it gave my junk"? Did you ignore the return value of `scanf`?

Comment: Note that a scan set such as `%[^\n]` finishes at the `]`.  The `s` will never be matched because the scan only stops when the next character is a newline, and a newline is not `s`.  Unless there's another conversion after it, though, you'll never know that the mismatch occurred; `scanf()` reports the number of successful conversions (1 in this case) and cannot report that the `s` didn't match.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` fails if the next character in the input stream is a `\n`, leaving `str` unchanged, if `str` is uninitialized, its contents may look like *junk*, printing that invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie: yes (valid and possibly relevant to the question as a whole), but tangential to the point I was making, which is that `%[…]` is a complete conversion specification, and the `s` after it is not part of the scan set at all.  You must check the return value from `scanf()` to stand a chance of knowing what's going on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I was adding to your pertinent comment, the OP, like many before him, might have assumed that `[...]` was a qualifier for the `%s` format. The fact that `%[^\n]` fails if no character is consumed is not completely intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take your input from command line arguments, you can specify an empty string with:

```
C:\>myprogram ""
```

`argc` will be `2` and `argv[1]` will be a pointer to an empty string.

Comment: I tried that also, just `printf("%s", argv);` gave me  `X§0` and `printf("%s", argv[1]);` crashed.

Comment: `printf("%s", argv);` has undefined behavior because `argv` is not a `char *`. Are you running your program directly?  The second printf should not crash. Post the source code for your program and print the value of `argc`.

Comment: Thanks It works! the second comment made it clear why I was going wrong: I was using `*argv` instead of `*argv[]`. Thanks again, hoping to get more ways to do it ( like in program, etc ).